# User navigates to folder, I save that folder location to a string

Tags: c#, filedialog

How can I do this?

I want a user to click a button and then a small window pops up and lets me end-user navigate to X folder. Then I need to save the location of the folder to a string variable.

Any help, wise sages of StackOverflow?

Comment: is this winforms? asp.net? what language?

Comment: Windows Form - C#(Check the tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    using (FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string s = dlg.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
```

(remove `this` if you aren't already in a winform)

Comment: It truly is ridiculous how quickly people help on this website. Thank you very much for the help. Works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Winforms, you can use a [FolderBrowserDialog control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx).  The path the user selects will be in the SelectedPath property.

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = null;
FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new ();
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    path = dlg.SelectedPath;
}
```